# Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy : Cannot find the Active Directory object '' in tenant

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I have two active directories as follow

1. Corporate
2. CorporateSub

All the users even my email id is present in `Corporate` directory and all the
resources/subscriptions are in `CorporateSub` directory.

I am following this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/always-encrypted-azure-key-vault-configure?tabs=azure-powershell to configure `Always Encrypted` by using Azure Key Vault.

The below `PowerShell` script fails

```
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy  -VaultName $vaultName  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServicePrincipalName $applicationId -PermissionsToKeys get,wrapKey,unwrapKey,sign,verify,list
```

**Error is,**

> Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy : Cannot find the Active Directory object '' in tenant `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Comment: I think you can create a multi-tenant azure ad app in CorporateSub. I assume that you created the application in Corporate.

Comment: @Tiny-wa  Yes, I have registered application in Corporate , that was the issue. now registering in CorporateSub resolved the issue.

Comment: The question you deleted just now, if using managed identity, you can access key vault with the line code     var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://xxx.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());  I don't know about the debug you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

As you update in the comment, the issue comes from the app is not registered in CorporateSub.

**Original Answer:**

I can reproduce the error:

[image]

Please make sure the application id is correct or you have log in the correct
account.

The app I tested is owned applications:

[image]